# Fast trigonometric approximations in python

Tags: python, performance, trigonometry, atan2, great-circle

I am using python for trajectory comparison calculations that require a lot of great circle computations. These calculations require a lot of trigonometric functions and the script is currently very slow with the regular math.atan2 etc. implementation. Is there any python library that performs time efficient approximations? I really prefer efficiency over accuracy here.

Any pointers to implement this myself are also much welcomed.

Comment: Did you profile the code to see what is the bottleneck? This looks like a shot in the dark

Comment: @JBernardo When I changed from simplistic Euclidean calculations to great circle, the run time went from nearly instant (<1.0s) to minutes for the same data. I thus do not really see how this is a shot in the dark

Comment: Without profiling it's mostly a shot in the dark. Also it's really important to get a rough idea about the execution times of parts of your script, so give it a try; it's a common way. You can do it quite easily with the module `cProfile`, which is included in python.

Comment: Perhaps you can find something useful [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411274/how-to-find-the-nearest-points-to-given-coordinates-with-matlab/17419323#17419323). If you want to go with the trig approach, why not use a rough lookup table? Compute the (inverse) sine/cosine/tangent of 100 points in the interval 0-2pi. Then, for every angle mod 2pi, you have a (rough) lookup table for all (inverse) trig functions of that angle. In cases where the lookup is indecisive, just compute the "real" values (in python+numpy, I doubt that this will be faster though...)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing. If you have data in matrix/vector format and want to pefrorm same operation on many elements you can use numpy.

```
data = np.array([...])
sines = np.sin(data)
```

This should speed up things quite a bit