# Join geo-referenced matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, geolocation, raster

I have two geo-referenced matrices (gridded climate datasets) with different spatial extent and resolution (i.e., spatial coverage of one pixel on the surface of the Earth) that I would like to join. Let's call them `referenceMatrix` and `targetMatrix`. The matrices can be loaded into MATLAB as geotiffs or just matrices with corresponding grids of latitudes/longitudes per pixel.

What I want is to fill `NaN`-pixels in the `targetMatrix` with the corresponding value from the `referenceMatrix`. I can do it using a `for`-loop that looks through the pixels one by one, and fills the `NaN`s in the `targetMatrix` with data from the `referenceMatrix` based on the nearest pixel. The method I am using to localize the nearest pixel in space is described here:
[How to find the nearest points to given coordinates with MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411274/how-to-find-the-nearest-points-to-given-coordinates-with-matlab)

However I need to do this with thousands of matrices, and the `for`-loop is too slow. Therefore I would like to use logical indexing, e.g.

```
targetMatrix(isnan(targetMatrix)) = referenceMatrix(isnan(targetMatrix))
```

with the added ability to match pixels in the matrices based on their latitude and longitude. Can any of you point me in a direction with an example of comparing matrices with different extent based on their georeference?

An example of input data and the wanted output below

```
targetMatrix = [1,  NaN, 3; 
                NaN, 5,  6]; 
referenceMatrix = [10, 20, 30, 40; 
                   50, 60, 70, 80]; 
referenceLatitude = [13.3, 13.3, 13.3, 13.3; 
                     14.1, 14.1, 14.1, 14.1]; 
referenceLongitude = [3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2; 
                      3.2, 4.2, 5.2, 6.2];  
targetLatitude = [13.4, 13.4, 13.4; 
                  13.9, 13.9, 13.9]; 
targetLongitude = [3.1, 3.6, 4.1; 
                   3.1, 3.6, 4.1]; 

wantedOutput = [ 1, 10, 3; 
                50,  5, 6];
```

The wanted output consists of the original values from the `targetMatrix` where the `NaN`s are filled with the nearest (in space) value from the `referenceMatrix`, i.e., `10` and `50`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added examples to the original post

Comment: All matrices are inputs except for the "wantedOutput"

Comment: The NaN in the `targetMatrix(1,2)` has the lat/lon coordinates (13.4, 3.6). The value 10 in the `referenceMatrix(1,1)` has the lat/lon coordinates (13.3, 3.2) and is thus the point located closest in space to `targetMatrix(1,2)`. The value 20 in the `referenceMatrix` has the lat/lon coordinates (13.3, 4.2) and the point is therefore further away in space from the `targetMatrix(1,2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find which entries of `targetMatrix` are to be replaced using [`isnan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html). Convert the lat/lon from degrees to radians and then to cartesian coordinates using [`sph2cart`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sph2cart.html) to get actual geodesic distances. Then use [`knnsearch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html)<sup>⬥</sup>  to find the indices of the points from the reference coordinates which are nearest to relevant targeted coordinates. Use these indices to extract the relevant entries from `referenceMatrix` and replace `NaN`s with them.

```
nanent = isnan(targetMatrix);
[tarX, tarY] = sph2cart(targetLongitude*pi/180, targetLatitude*pi/180, 1);
[refX, refY] = sph2cart(referenceLongitude*pi/180, referenceLatitude*pi/180, 1);
tmptar = [tarY(nanent) tarX(nanent)];
tmpref = [refY(:) refX(:)];
ind = knnsearch(tmpref, tmptar);
wantedOutput = targetMatrix;
wantedOutput(nanent) = referenceMatrix(ind);
```

In this case, converting lat/lon to cartesian coordinates prior to the use of `knnsearch` is tested<sup>**ⵜ**</sup> to sped up `knnsearch` than otherwise.

`knnsearch` finds euclidean distance by default. You can also do this using a combination of [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html)<sup>⬥</sup> and [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) instead of `knnsearch` (in line 6). i.e.

```
[~, ind] = min(pdist2(tmptar, tmpref), [], 2);
```

or you can use `desearchn` in line 6. i.e.

```
ind = dsearchn(tmpref, tmptar);
```

But `knnsearch` is tested<sup>**ⵜ**</sup> to be faster than `dsearchn` in this case.

---

<sub><sup>⬥</sup>`knnsearch` and `pdist2` require ≥ R2010a with Stats and ML Toolbox. Use `dsearchn` if you do not have that.</sub>
<sub><sup>**ⵜ**</sup> All tests are done by the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275421/).</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. Some of the data is close to the poles and the 180 degree meridian, so I think using `distance()` may be a better option than euclidian distance, since it takes the spherical shape into account. Another thing is that the size of the matrices I have is 2000 x 2000. Therefore using the `pdist2` is not an option since it creates an array of 2000^4. `dsearchn` is a neat function, thank you introducing it, however it takes equally long time to index the combinations for one set of matrices as it does using a for-loop.

Comment: @user3275421 try with `knnsearch` as suggested above

Comment: Thanks again for your input. The good news is that using the knnsearch works fast. The bad news is that it still computes distance on a flat surface (default is euclidian). This distance measure is different from the geodesic distance (i.e., the distance when travelling on the surface of a ball or ellipsoid). The `distance` function can do this but again I struggle to implement this function in a logical indexing scheme.

Comment: In fact, what could be done would be to use `distance` as a custom distance function in `knnsearch` according to the Matlab documentation. I am trying to figure the syntax out, but input on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @user3275421 In that case, this may be as simple as `ind = knnsearch(tmpref, tmptar,'Distance',@distance);` (I didn't test it)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I tried it out and it works, however the processing time is >60 minutes per matrix, and I have 47000 so it won't work. I will rethink the workflow, and probably try to regrid the matrices so they match geographically and in terms of spatial resolution

Comment: @user3275421 What is the size of your matrices? How much available memory do you have? It is quite possible that you're running out of memory

Comment: Thanks, memory is not the issue (128 gb ram, only using approx 8 gb), and 28-core Xeon workstation. The matrices are 1200 x 1200 (double). It seems the integration of `distance` in `knnsearch` is slow or that it should be integrated in another way.

Comment: @user3275421 I don't think there is any issue with the integration

Comment: I have solved the problem by converting the Lat/Lon to cartesian coordinates with `sph2cart` (convert degrees to radians prior to the cartesian conversion) and then use your idea with the `knnsearch`. This is a very fast solution in terms of processing speed, and then I get the actual geodesic distance. If you add the step with cartesian coordinates, I can acknowledge your answer. Thanks

Comment: @user3275421 You're welcome. You can edit my answer to include your insight by clicking edit button under my answer, I'll approve your edit.